# How to properly run NextJS (13.4) on IIS?

Tags: node.js, iis, next.js

ExpressJS apps work fine on IIS but when i tried to install a NextJS I ran into this error

[image]

I Followed the guidelines from this [article](https://medium.com/@dipneupane/deploying-nextjs-application-on-windows-iis-server-cabdc22bccf8#:%7E:text=Publishing%20NextJs%20application%20on%20IIS,js%2C%20and%20web.)  but it seems like I am missing something.

Project Setup

[image]

I have Created app.js as entry point on the root folder containing this code:

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = process.env.port || 5000
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, }) // Here i tried including and removing port and hostname with same result
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer(async (req, res) => {
        try {
            // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
            // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
            const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
            const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

            if (pathname === '/a') {
                await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
            } else if (pathname === '/b') {
                await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
            } else {
                await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
            res.statusCode = 500
            res.end('internal server error')
        }
    })
        .once('error', (err) => {
            console.error(err)
            process.exit(1)
        })
        .listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
        })
})
```

Then added this web.config file :

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>

<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />

<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="nodejs">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/app.js" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite> 

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <add segment="node_modules" />
      <add segment="iisnode" />
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and Edited the package.json scripts as following :

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "node app.js",
"build": "next build",
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
"lint": "next lint"
},
```

Then I run the build command and create a site on IIS with basic settings

[image]

The app seems to work fine when I run "npm run dev" from visual studio terminal.
But I get 404.2 error when I run from IIS.
please advice.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs Just a few simple steps with HttpPlatformHandler.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you are facing 404.2 error, you could try the web.config below, if it not works, you can [follow the official doc to check the issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/site-behavior-performance/http-error-402-webpage).

Change your code like below:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />

  </system.webServer>
    <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
        <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I have downloaded and deployed the project, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: I Tried these configs but no luck.
I also flowed the instructions in the mentioned link but all restrictions are already set to allow.  They all start with ASP.net.. or Active Server Pages  do i need to add something for NodeJS ?

Comment: @Same How about the repo, I mean you can download the repo from the blog, and make sure it can be running in you local and follow the steps and check what will happen.

Comment: @Same Then I could help you compare the difference between your side and mine.

Comment: Repo works fine locally but I get this error when i host it on server iis : DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

Comment: @Same Ok, pls share your nodejs version, npm version

Comment: @Same https://i.imgur.com/Gp8QqtE.png It's my environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and I think the problem is in a pipe used by iisnode instead of a numeric port.

A simple solution to resolve this issue is to create http-proxy server **and** next.js server.

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { createProxyServer } = require('http-proxy');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const hostname = 'localhost';
const nextJsPort = 12007;

const startNextJsServer = () => {
    // your current code starting next.js server, but using nextJsPort variable as port
};

const startProxyServer = () => {
    const proxy = createProxyServer({});

    const httpProxyPort = process.env.PORT;
    const httpProxyTargetServer = `http://${hostname}:${nextJsPort}`;

    createServer((req, res) => {
        proxy.web(req, res, { target: httpProxyTargetServer }, err => {
            console.error('Error occurred handling redirection', err);
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.end('Internal proxy server error');
        });
    }).listen(httpProxyPort, () => {
        console.log(`Proxy server ready on ${httpProxyPort}`);
    });
};

startNextJsServer();
startProxyServer();
```

Answer (score -2):

just add this line in your `package.json`

```json
"export": "npm run build && next export -o _next",
```

then with running:

```bash
npm run export
```

`_next` folder will be created, point IIS to this folder, done.

Comment: IIS does not natively support Node.js, so saying "done" is too early. Besides, `next export` can fail in many cases (for example it does not work with App Router), so this isn't a universal solution.